# анимация рывками в браузерах

Tags: three.js, webgl

Здравствуйте. Создал на three.js анимацию логотипа. 
Проверял на разных браузерах и машинах. На рабочем компе все отлично в любом браузере (IE не беру в расчет). Тянет в моём мобильнике в Chrome for Android, на древнем компьютере у меня дома со встроенной видеокартой в процессор.
Но, как назло, у заказчика на довольно так приличном компьютере тормозит, крутится рывками.

Сейчас сайт висит здесь - http://agropiter.com
Код (пока в хаотичном немного состоянии) тут  - https://github.com/davegahn/FORUM/blob/master/dev/js/logo.js

Сначала открывали у заказчика в хроме (обновлен, последняя версия) - вылезают вот такие вот ошибки:

- WebGl_depth_texture extension not supported
- OES_Texture_float_linear extension not supported

Критичные ли это ошибки. Рендеринг ведь происходит, тормозит именно анимация.
Конечно можно поковыряться в флагами в хроме, но мне кажется что это не выход. Не будешь ведь у всех кому нужен сайт настраивать хром?...

Сегодня попробовал у заказчика в Яндекс браузере - вылезает что WEbGL заблокирован вплоть до черного экрана.
В мониторе ресурсов никаких перегрузов памяти и ЦП. Видеокарта Radeon7400 хорошая. Система Windows7.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста варианты решения.

Comment: Можно задать вопрос на форуме https://discourse.threejs.org/, правда он англоязычный.

Comment: Гляньте в консоль. Выполните что просит библиотека `THREE.WebGLRenderer: image is not power of two (2480x3508). Resized to 2048x2048`. Посмотрите на следующие ошибки. Это уже ближе к настройкам. Как консоль замолчит - тогда уже проблемы с WebGL решать.